# How to keep SE from scaling my images?

Tags: support

When I upload an image for a question/answer on SE, the site seems to scale it to fit the standard post width.

Often this is useful since it gives a nice uniform clean look to the post.  But sometimes it's annoying, such as when I want to put a small image inline with the text, or if I am trying to put multiple images side by side, or just if my image is too small to be scaled up that much.

Can I keep SE from scaling the images I upload?  Or (even better) control the scaling manually?

Comment: Images are never upsampled AFAIK. If your image is smaller than the width of the post, it should [work as expected](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/45679/599)

Comment: @gandalf3  [This image](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1028/se-com-all-sites-logo-wrong) is [definitely scaled up](http://i.stack.imgur.com/RPJO8.png).

Comment: It looks like the file itself has been upsampled. Right click > view image shows it just as it appears in the post for me.

Comment: @gandalf3  So you think imgur is scaling the images?

Comment: idk, that's really odd. I've never seen it do that for me..

Comment: @gandalf3 It does that to me all the time.  I often turn my DPI scaling way up to take screenshots so I can get them higher res to minimize this effect.

Comment: I don't suppose it's possible your screenshot taking software might be doing this? Can you check if images look upscaled prior to uploading?

Comment: @gandalf3  That's definitely not it I just use good old fashioned print screen and MS paint.  And they don't look upsampled before uploading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify a height and width by inserting the image via a HTML tag.

1. Upload your image via the standard image uploader, copy the image address and delete it.
2. Copy this line of HTML into the editor and insert the values:

`<img src="insertImageLocationHere" width="insertWidthHere" alt="insertAltTextHere">`

**Notes:**

- The attributes MUST be listed in this order
- There is no need to specify a height attribute, it should keep the aspect ratio
- DO NOT include the `px` extension for the width attribute

**Example:**

Standard Markdown

[image: A wide image]

HTML tag: `<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoGVY.png" width="500" alt="A wide image">`

[image: A wide image]

(not anymore!!)

Comment: What's the `alt` attribute do?

Comment: @PGmath you know how in markdown it asks you to insert an image description? Same thing here. The Alt (alternate) text is displayed if the image is not available or if a screen reader is used.